# How do I properly set these javascript proxies up?

Tags: javascript, proxies

I'm trying to set up proxies for the player and opponent characters for this game I'm making. Basically I want the game to print the gameover screen when the player / opponent's health are set to 0.

I've tried defining the character objects in their own variables and that didn't work. Now I have the proxies point to new instances of the characters I am representing in the game. This kind of works, as the program now recognizes that when I call proxy.method, that the method is of the objects the proxy points to. But when I try to run the code, the health bars don't change at all.

```
// function to attack if the coolDown is false
function attack(character, move, other, coolDown) {
  if(coolDown.getValue() === false) {
    character.makeMove(move, other);
    coolDown.setValue(true);
  }
}


const HANDLER = {
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    console.log(`obj = ${obj} prop = ${prop} value = ${value}`);
    obj.prop = value;
    if(prop === 'health') {
      if(obj.prop.value === 0) {
        gameover(true);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
};

var playerCoolDown = new CoolDownTime(false);
var player = new Proxy(new Character(PLAYER_HP), HANDLER);
var opponent = new Proxy(new Character(OPP_HP), HANDLER);

setInterval(() => playerCoolDown.setValue(false), 2000);
setInterval(() => opponent.makeMove('KICK', player), 2000);

player.updateHealth();
opponent.updateHealth();

// event listeners for various moves
PUNCH.addEventListener('click', () => {attack(player, 'PUNCH', opponent, playerCoolDown)});
KICK.addEventListener('click', () => {attack(player, 'KICK', opponent, playerCoolDown)});
HEAL.addEventListener('click', () => {attack(player, 'HEAL', opponent, 
playerCoolDown)});
EXTERMINATE.addEventListener('click', () => {attack(player, 'EXTERMINATE', opponent, playerCoolDown)});
```

I expect `console.log('obj = ${obj}')` to print out Character, but instead it prints out [object Object]. When I run `console.log('${obj.prop}'}` I get undefined. BUT, when I call `console.log('prop = %{prop} value = ${value}')`, I get the correct values, 'health', and some value decremented form 100 (what it should be, the health starts at 100). But after it's called again, its a new value decremented by 100, almost like the proxy is instantiating a new Character object every time the health value is reset. (Just an observation, I don't know if that helps at all)

Comment: when console.log'ing a string, any object will be output as `[object Object]`, that's just how `({}).toString()` works - try, instead `console.log(\`obj = ${JSON.stringify(obj)}\` ...` etc

Comment: alternatively `console.log('obj =', obj, 'prop =', prop, 'value =', value);`

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks man.

Comment: now for the object all I get are variations of {"health":100,"display":{},"prop":94}

Comment: Okay, that helped out a lot. I changed obj.prop = value to obj[prop] = value and it works now. looks like it thought I was trying to modify a property called prop.

Comment: well, you were .. obj.prop accesses the property called prop ... obj[prop] access the property of the value of prop